# Back button prematurely closes the app on Android using Titanium SDK 7.0.0 version

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When I close the window on back button app force close and this issue only happening for Android 7.0.0.

```
$.Win.addEventListener('android:back', function(e) { if ($.Win != null && $.Win != undefined) { $.Win.close(); } });


04-10 11:52:07.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 11:52:07.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18067): Process: com.getattendantapp, PID: 18067
04-10 11:52:07.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18067): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
04-10 11:52:07.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18067):    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:468)
04-10 11:52:07.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18067):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4841)
```

Comment: Please provide some code what you have used that causes the error

Comment: $.Win.addEventListener('android:back', function(e) {
 if ($.Win != null && $.Win != undefined) {
  $.Win.close();
 }
});

Comment: I don't know this technology but still I suggest you to Add the code in the question

Comment: 7.0.0 is from Dec. 2017 so I strongly advice you to update the SDK since there are many bugfixes (and new features). Does it close normally if you use `exitOnClose` and don't use the `android:back` event at all?

Comment: @miga I am using titanium SDK 7.1.1 for my project and force close issue occurring on android device with version 7.0.0 
even if I have not used android:back and close the window on the back arrow still facing force close issue and it's happening only on android 7.0.0 version device

$.backView.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
  $.Win.close(); 
});

and when I add exitOnClose true for the same window then on the closing of the window whole application exit.

Comment: I only know this ticket https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24839 where your error occurs (modifing a listview in a closed window by a module). But this https://gist.github.com/m1ga/f15f7ac4926b6017ad794f50f160406d works fine for me with 7.3.0.GA (lowest SDK I have) and Android 7. So if that is the case for you too it is some element in your window not the close function

Comment: @miga Thank you for the help. 
In my case, it works after adding fullscreen to true for that window.